# Swift AVAsset downloading from iCloud has no permission on iOS 14: error Code=257

Tags: swift, cloud, ios14, avasset

All my work worked well before iOS 14...

I display video from Library on my app. I succeeded to display all of them from iCloud or from the local storage.
But since iOS 14, impossible to read them from iCloud and I don't find any solution...

The code:

```
    let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
    options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    options.version = .original
    options.progressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in
        log.infoMessage("progress: \(progress)")
    }
    
    PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: options, resultHandler: {(avAsset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
        if let asset = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
            Queue.main {
                Player.shared.replaceAssetBy(AVPlayerItem(url: asset.url))
                self.playerLayer.player = Player.shared.player
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.loopAction), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: Player.shared.player.currentItem)
            }
        }
    })
```

The error:
`FAILED Optional("Impossible d’ouvrir le fichier car vous ne disposez pas de l’autorisation nécessaire pour l’afficher.") -- error: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "Impossible d’ouvrir le fichier car vous ne disposez pas de l’autorisation nécessaire pour l’afficher." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x2814398c0 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12203 "(null)"}})`

Sorry The error is in french...

Just before some of you ask, I've already made the modification about rights with the `.ReadWrite` on the requestPermission new on iOS 14.

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two ways:

- try `options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat`

or

- use `requestExportSession` instad of `requestAVAsset`.
  Then use `session.asset`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both are working well! 
I use the second option because I can manage the size of the asset with it.